# n closest points in a set of lat/long coordinates

Tags: sorting, databases, nearest-neighbour

Here's my problem:

I have a website where people can search based on their location (which is converted to lat/long coordinates). I have many products stored in a database with their lat/long coordinates. I also have a function to calculate the distance between two points based on their coordinates.

Now I'm looking for a way to find one of these things:

- The n nearest products to the user's location.
- All the products within a radius of x kilometers from the user's location.

Both solutions would be fine for my application.

Currently I just iterate over all the database entries, find their distance, and sort them. This obviously gets way too slow with a lot of entries.

Are there any algorithms/data structures I can apply here to make it faster?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (at least the second variant) is known as *2D range searching*. Commonly used data structures are [range trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) and [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Searching for *range searching* on the web will open you a window into the area. These [lecture notes](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/RangeSearching.pdf) come up, for example.